# Where is SBT documentation of sbt.TaskKey and sbt.SettingKey?

Tags: sbt

I'm interested in figuring out what some of the operations of `sbt.TaskKey` or `sbt.SettingKey` do

```
<<=
<+=
<++=
```

I know there are a lot of examples and docs in the document section of the main website, but I didn't find anything of help. Here's where I looked:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/More-About-Settings.html

http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/api/index.html#sbt.TaskKey

http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/api/index.html#sbt.SettingKey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### sbt 0.12 syntax

If you want to learn about `<<=`-family of the operators, the best place to go is sbt 0.12.1 version of the Getting Started guide, specifically the page you linked More Kinds of Setting has a section called [Computing a value based on other keys' values: <<=](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.1/docs/Getting-Started/More-About-Settings.html#computing-a-value-based-on-other-keys-values).

> `~=` defines a new value in terms of a key's previously-associated value. But what if you want to define a value in terms of other keys' values?
>
> - `<<=` lets you compute a new value using the value(s) of arbitrary other keys.
>
> `<<=` has one argument, of type `Initialize[T]`. An `Initialize[T]` instance is a computation which takes the values associated with a set of keys as input, and returns a value of type `T` based on those other values. It initializes a value of type `T`.
>
> Given an `Initialize[T]`, `<<=` returns a `Setting[T]`, of course (just like `:=`, `+=`, `~=`, etc.).

As noted in the document, `<<=` makes you think in terms of `Initialize[T]`, so if you want to extract values out of multiple keys and compose it in some way, you'd need to do something like:

```
jarName in assembly <<= (name, version) map { (n, v) =>
  n + "-assembly-" + v + ".jar" }
```

At this point you have to know somehow that `jarName` is a `TaskKey` not a `SettingKey`.

### sbt 0.13 syntax

The reason you did not find `<<=` in the latest Getting Started guide, is that the sbt 0.13 syntax makes `<<=` obsolete. All you need is `:=`. sbt uses macro to expand the rhs of the `:=` to generate the above out of this:

```
jarName in assembly := {
  name.value + "-assembly-" + version.value + ".jar"
}
```

`:=` lets you think in `T`, so it's easier to deal with.

Comment: does that mean that "<<=" is deprecated? would you say that the "<++=" and "<+=" operators are also obsolete and are basically replaced by "++=" and "+="?

Comment: It's officially *deprecated* when sbt deprecates it with `@deprecated`. At this point, we can say `:=` macro is encouraged over `<<=`. Since the document that used to have `<+=` and `<++=` now says `+=` and `++=`, I'd say the same applies for them too.